# Setting width with CSS attr()

Tags: css

I'm trying to set the width of an element using attr() in CSS but it's not working. Chrome says "invalid property value" but I'm not sure what's wrong.

I'm trying to use the attribute "prog" as the width in percent for the .progress div.

[Here's my example on codepen.](http://codepen.io/dbs727/pen/fDxqs)

```
<div class="progresscontainer">
    <div class="progress" prog="10">
    </div>
</div>

.progresscontainer {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:black;
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.progress {
    background-color: green;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent -100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%, transparent 200%), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, lime 0%, lightgreen 50%, green 50%, darkgreen 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent -100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%, transparent 200%), -moz-linear-gradient(top, lime 0%, lightgreen 50%, green 50%, darkgreen 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, transparent -100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%, transparent 200%), -ms-linear-gradient(top, lime 0%, lightgreen 50%, green 50%, darkgreen 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, transparent -100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%, transparent 200%), linear-gradient(top, lime 0%, lightgreen 50%, green 50%, darkgreen 100%);
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width: attr(prog %);
}
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This is an experimental, or at least draft, feature of CSS, and currently, according to Mozilla Developer Network's documentation, is only compatible with the CSS `content` property (in which it can return a string to be placed inside a pseudo-element), but cannot (yet) be used to generate values for other properties.

References:

- [`attr()` (at MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr).
- [`attr()` (at W3C)](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#attr-notation).

Comment: I suppose I'm too getting ambitious. Do you have any idea on what kind of a time frame this could become available in the future?

Comment: Unfortunately, no; it depends on when, or even *if*, browser vendors want to support it.

Comment: According to MDN: "The attr() expression can be used with any CSS property.", but I can't get it to work, so maybe some time ever...

Comment: @DavidThomas I need to be able to dynamically set the width of a pseudo element using js, is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 12):

There is actually a way to get attributes / variables from html (or your template framework) to css, using var() (see [this article](https://css-tricks.com/css-attr-function-got-nothin-custom-properties/) for more info)

```css
.progress {
    width: var(--prog);
}

/* Rest of styling */
.progresscontainer {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:black;
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.progress {
    background-color: green;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent -100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%, transparent 200%), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, lime 0%, lightgreen 50%, green 50%, darkgreen 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent -100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%, transparent 200%), -moz-linear-gradient(top, lime 0%, lightgreen 50%, green 50%, darkgreen 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, transparent -100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%, transparent 200%), -ms-linear-gradient(top, lime 0%, lightgreen 50%, green 50%, darkgreen 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, transparent -100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%, transparent 200%), linear-gradient(top, lime 0%, lightgreen 50%, green 50%, darkgreen 100%);
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progresscontainer">
    <div class="progress" style="--prog: 10%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: inline css :D hmmm

Comment: @Rizkiramadhani Yeah you're right, inline styling is usually not the way to go, but you would still put all your other styling in a normal stylesheet, and only put the variables in an inline tag.

Comment: I am building a slider to show a value and this tip saved my life. Yes, I am fiercely against inline styles and all for separation of concerns, namely format and content, but for a generated page on a jinja2 template, this is milk and honey, whereas input range is just pain. THANK YOU @ArthurVanPassel!

Comment: For most practical uses, I find this to be the best/easiest way to avoid `attr()`.

Answer (score 11):

Actually, **there is a way to get around the `attr()` solution**:

I don't recommend this, but you could account for every scenario of `data-width` attribute, for example:

(stylus code)

```
$limit = 300

.myClass
    for num in (1...$limit)
        &[data-width="${limit}"]
            width $limit
```

Albeit, this is a terrible approach, and leads to **way** too much CSS.  I just wanted to point out that there's always a way.

Comment: I had to wash my eyes out with soap after seeing this. You just generated 15KB of CSS that will hurt browser performance, and you might miss out of range values or decimals. I would sooner tell the client "nope, can't do your project" than this.

Comment: http://thecodinglove.com/post/168284383940/when-a-senior-dev-takes-a-look-at-my-code

Comment: Most people cannot read Stylus: when I run this through an online stylus compiler I get 300 exactly the same faulty CSS declarations. It might be the compiler at fault, but I for one have only an inkling of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

[Support for attributes other than content is Experimental](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr).  In other words, browsers do not support this yet even though it is seemingly valid.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/BgZN9/) showing that it does work with `content`, but not `width`.