# Change pseudo :before background color using CSS attr()

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use CSS `attr()` to change background color of a pseudo `:before` element.

```
<ul>
    <li data-color="#ff0000">R</li>
    <li data-color="#00ff00">G</li>
    <li data-color="#0000ff">B</li>
</ul>
```

Here's the CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li:before {
    background-color: attr(data-color, color);
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

But the before element doesn't show background color according to the `data-color` attribute.

But when I add this CSS

```
li:after {
    content: attr(data-color);
}
```

The `:after` element shows the `data-color` attribute content as the content.

Here's the JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b7Rve/

What did I do wrong?

**UPDATE**

I just reread about `color` in the [Mozilla developer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr). It says that `color` type is experimental. I guess I still need to wait until it's released.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please, look at this other thread [**Setting width with CSS attr()**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408488/setting-width-with-css-attr?answertab=active#tab-top).

In short: "*according to Mozilla Developer Network's documentation, is only compatible with the CSS content property [...], but cannot (yet) be used to generate values for other properties.*"

---

**UPDATE MAY 16, 2016**:

Looking at [Mozilla Developer Network's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) now is possibile but with caution:

> The attr() function can be used with any CSS property, but support for
>   properties other than content is experimental.

So, actually you can use it but surely browsers' support, altough better than in the past, is still only rare and experimental.

Comment: It would be nice to have this as a feature, but I imagine it'll be a long way off, once Object.Observe is in full implementation. The strain on browsers to need to adjust stylesheets dynamically whenever DOM values change, would be a lot of work!