# CSS use title text to get background-image url

Tags: css

I currently have a little problem, but I think it is not possible to do it with only css3, I want to get a image name from the title attribute and use it on the background-image url, like this:

```
#wizHeader li a[title^="step_"]{
    background-image: url("../images/" + attr(title) + ".png");
}
```

is this possible with only css3?

Comment: No thats not possible with CSS3, you have to write some JS on page load and have this behavior.

Comment: It's completely possible with CSS3 alright... [but as of now not a single browser supports 'Usage in other properties than content and with non-string values'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presently not possible. The `attr` function in CSS has great potential but, to my knowledge, at least cross-browser, it is presently usable only as part of the `content` property of pseudo elements, e.g.

```
.foo:after { content: attr(title); }
```

Further info [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408488/setting-width-with-css-attr).

And [here on CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/).

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wizHeader li a[title^="step_"]').each(function(k, v) {
        var title = $(v).attr('title');
        $(v).attr('style', 'background-image: url("../images/' + title + '.png")');
    });
});
```

Comment: A reasonable workaround, but the question didn't mention jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: Umm yeah but isn't this better than a plain "no you cant do it with css3"?

Comment: Depends. The question was about doing it with CSS, so the answer, though not good news, is that you can't. It's fine to suggest alternative approaches, but comments are for that. The OP didn't indicate he was willing to use JS.

Comment: -1 for [answering jQuery to a question where it's completely irrelevant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/219504).

Comment: @Ananth you're just not answering the question, which is "can I do this with ***only*** CSS3". 99% chance that OP knows perfectly well he can do this with generic Javascript, or with a library like jQuery or Mootools. But your answer is about as offtopic as answering "what color is the sky" with "cars can drive" - you're not even **addressing** the actual question, which boils down to "can I...".

Comment: Yes I know that with JS i can solve this perfectly fine and easily but I wanted to know if this was possible, but until now it's not possible but thank you anyway