# css3: Trying to apply dynamically translate3d to ::after

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to move a speudo `::after` element using `translate3d`

If I hardcode this it can easily be done as follows:

```
div::after {
    ...
    transform: translate3d(40px, 40px, 0);
}
```

But now I would like to apply any value for the `X` direction using javascript. So I tried the following:

```
div::after {
    ...
    transform: translate3d(attr(distance-to px), 40px, 0);
}
```

And in the HTML

```
<div distance-to="40"></div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0fq5zcp0/)

But this doesn't work. I assume I'm doing something wrong (hopefully), any suggestions ?

Comment: answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408488/setting-width-with-css-attr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attr() CSS value on anything else but the 'content' attribute is not supported in any browser. Therefore it can not work.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr#Browser_compatibility) on that.