# Why CSS styles for flex's order: attr(data-order) are marked as invalid?

Tags: css

For the following HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="bdg" data-order="4">1</div>
  <div class="bdg" data-order="3">2</div>
  <div class="bdg" data-order="2">3</div>
  <div class="bdg" data-order="1">4</div>
</div>
```

I have this CSS using [`attr()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr):

```
.parent { display: flex; }
.bdg { order: attr(data-order number, 5000); }
```

and it is marked by a browser (Chrome):

> ⚠️ Invalid property value

[image]

I've also tried doing it both without `attr()`'s 3rd *default value* argument:

```
.bdg { order: attr(data-order number); }
```

and without `attr()`'s 2nd *type* and the 3rd *default value* arguments:

```
.bdg { order: attr(data-order); }
```

Running example:

```css
.parent { display: flex; }
.bdg { order: attr(data-order number, 5000); }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="bdg" data-order="4">1</div>
  <div class="bdg" data-order="3">2</div>
  <div class="bdg" data-order="2">3</div>
  <div class="bdg" data-order="1">4</div>
</div>
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Other forms from simple `attr(data-attribute)` has no [implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr#browser_compatibility) in any browser
2. `attr` only works with `:before`/`:after` `content` rule, as stated in first top-most [*note*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr#browser_compatibility#sect1)

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.bdg:before {
  content: attr(data-order);
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="bdg" data-order="4">1</div>
  <div class="bdg" data-order="3">2</div>
  <div class="bdg" data-order="2">3</div>
  <div class="bdg" data-order="1">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out `attr()` is still experimental and works only with the `content` propery - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18408592/6439240).

I ended up using `var()` instead.

```css
.parent { display: flex; }
.bdg { order: var(--order); }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="bdg" style="--order: 4">1</div>
  <div class="bdg" style="--order: 3">2</div>
  <div class="bdg" style="--order: 2">3</div>
  <div class="bdg" style="--order: 1">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `attrs()` default `<type-or-unit>` is a string so your `order` property is invalid

And any other value that the value name is non supported yet ([See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr#browser_compatibility))